# Using a version of Angular smaller than the one I installed do I have to uninstall the project installation?

Tags: angular, installation, version, uninstallation

Using Angular 9, I found that I can create a new Angular project from a lower version, but I need to use the command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@number.version
```

But will that version work for this project only?

So, if I use the command

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

I completely end Angular within this project and I will have to give another command

```
"npm install -g @angular/cli@number.version"
```

to reinstall this version or another within this project?

Will this modify the packages within the project that I am changing the version of?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why npm install -g @angular/cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828865/why-npm-install-g-angular-cli)

Comment: I changed the question. I want to know inside the project already installed, if I can uninstall and change the version of Angular without any problem? I've had a lot of problems with minor version changes that made me abandon everything and create a new project because I couldn't find the defect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend installing angular cli globally.

Whenever, I need to create new application, I use the npx command.

```sh
> npx @angular/cli@10 new pdf-viewer --strict --defaults true
> npx @angular/cli new console --strict --create-application false
```

And once I generate a new angular application, and I am inside the application directory, I use `yarn` package manager to invoke local @angular/cli

```sh
> cd <project folder>
> yarn ng generate component components/home
> yarn ng generate service services/error-handler/error-handler
```

Comment: Now, how do I uninstall Angular globally and follow what you explain? "npm uninstall -g @ angular/cli" uninstalls it completely? Because I did this and when I checked the version there was still one installed. Then I didn't understand anything! I didn't know if I was uninstalling it from within the project or from my entire OS..

Comment: You can use `npm list --global --depth 0` to find a list of globally installed binaries by npm. If using `yarn`, you can use `yarn global list`. If `@angular/cli` doesn't appear in the list, then use `which` command to locate the path of `ng` binary. Related question to find path of `ng` binary: https://superuser.com/questions/49104/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-an-executable-in-windows